# listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

Im using the following code in order to change the list box **specific item color like grayed out or just gray instead black** when you D&D from list box to text box(that the user indicate that this specific item was already dragged),the problem here that lbi is always retruened as null any idea why ? when debug the user object is the correct item which was dragged and the list box is not empty. maybe I need to do addtional thing?

Maybe there is diffent way to do that?

```
private void DropText_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
  ...
                DataObject data = e.Data as DataObject;
                User user = data.GetData(typeof(User)) as User;

                ListBoxItem lbi = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(user) as ListBoxItem;
                if (lbi != null)
                    lbi.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Returns null if the item does not belong to the item collection, or if a UIElement has not been generated for it.

So this means that either your `user` object is not the *actual* item from the `listBox.Items` collection, or `listBox` is not the *actual* `ListBox` object that contains the `user` object. If you have a unique property in the `User` class, then you can retrieve the *actual* `User` object from the `ListBox` collection like this:

```
User actualUser = listBox.Items.Cast<User>().Where(u => u.Id == user.Id);
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
ListBoxItem lbi = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(actualUser)
    as ListBoxItem;
```